# How to implement the view in a manyToMany field?

Tags: java, spring, forms, many-to-many, submit

Anyone have success in implement in a html view a manyToMany field, like that one:

```
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name="listaDeProdutosEmDestaque", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_destaque")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_produto")})
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  private List<Produto> listaDeProdutos;
```

I have tried this options, none of them works:

```
<select class="form-control" name="listaDeProdutos[]" multiple="multiple" rows="7">
    ...
    <option value="1">one</option>
    ...
</select>
```

I get the error: `NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`.

```
<select class="form-control" name="listaDeProdutos" multiple="multiple" rows="7">
    ...
    <option value="1">one</option>
    ...
</select>
```

the form is submited without errors, but no selected option is stored in the database

```
<select class="form-control" name="listaDeProdutos.id" multiple="multiple" rows="7">
    ...
    <option value="1">one</option>
    ...
</select>
```

same as previous: form submited without errors, but no data is stored in database.

**UPDATE**

the form submission is handled by this controller/service methods:

--controller class

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(value="icone", required=false) MultipartFile icone, @RequestParam(value="fotos", required=false) MultipartFile fotos[], @RequestParam(value="arquivo", required=false) MultipartFile arquivo[]) throws Exception {
    serv.cadastra(object);
    serv.upload(object, icone);
    serv.upload_multiplo(object, fotos);
    serv.upload_jar(object, arquivo);
  }
```

--service class

```
  @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
  @Transactional
  public void cadastra(E object) {
    dao.insert(object);
  }
```

the view is mapped in this way:

--controller class

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "cadastra")
  @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
  @Menu(label = "cadastra")
  public String cadastra(Model model) throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute("command", serv.newObject());
    return "private/cadastra";
  }
```

--service class

```
  public E newObject() throws Exception {
    return (E) clazz.newInstance();
  }
```

**UPDATE 2**

in the controller:

```
  @InitBinder
  public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Pagina.class, new PaginaEditor());
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Produto.class, new ProdutoEditor());
  }
```

property editor class:

```
@Component
public class ProdutoEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
  @Autowired
  private ProdutoService produtoService;

  @Override
  public void setAsText(String text) {
    System.out.println("produtoEditor");
    if (!text.equals("")) {
      System.out.println("not empty");
      Produto produto = produtoService.getObject(text);
      setValue(produto);
    } else {
      System.out.println("empty");
      setValue(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your controller code or how are you populating java object with form values.

Comment: @RRR question updated with the requested code.

Comment: You have to narrow down the problem's location. Try to print what's received in the controller. If the object is ok in the controller method, your problem is in your service or database. If the object is not the right one in the controller, the problem comes from the request between the form and the controller. Can you try that?

Comment: @VincentDurmont I did print what the controller is receving, and I see all attributes receive the correct value, except the List ones, which receive the null value. I try add a Property Editor in my project (see update 2), but still don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve this issue changing the Property Editor class to this:

```
@Component
public class ProdutoEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
  @Override
  public void setAsText(String text) {
    if (!text.equals("")) {
      ProdutoService serv = new ProdutoService();
      ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(serv);
      Produto produto = serv.getObject(text);
      setValue(produto);
    } else {
      setValue(null);
    }
  }
}
```

which work with this select code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="listaDeProdutos" multiple="multiple" rows="7">
    ...
    <option value="1">one</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<select class="form-control" name="listaDeProdutos[0].id" rows="7">
    ...
    <option value="1">one</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Just for adding one at index 0, and then handle through javascript the correct indexes/values and adding/removing a select dropdown.

Anyway, you can also try this one:

```
<select class="form-control" name="listaDeProdutos[].id" multiple="multiple" rows="7">
    ...
    <option value="1">one</option>
    ...
</select>
```